# JLabel only sometimes shows on JPanel

Tags: jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I'm trying to get my title to appear on my JPanel but when I run the program, the text will only appear sometimes. I'm not sure why it's not appearing all the time and don't know how to fix it.

```
window = new JFrame();
window.setSize(800, 600);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.orange);
window.setLayout(null);
window.setVisible(true);
container = window.getContentPane();


titlePanel = new JPanel();
titlePanel.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 150);
titlePanel.setBackground(Color.white);
titleLabel = new JLabel("Program's Title");
titleLabel.setForeground(Color.black);
titlePanel.add(titleLabel);
container.add(titlePanel);
```

Comment: Use window.setVisible(true); after adding all the element

Comment: wow I was trying to put that too early thanks

Comment: Or call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container to force it to update